# Cosets: Define a 1-1 and onto function from $Hg \to H$, where $H \le G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Cosets: Define a 1-1 and onto function from $Hg \to H$, where $H \le G$

Define $f: Hg \to H \\ \,\,\,\,\,\,\, hg \mapsto h $

this seems a little to0 easy.

1-1: $f(hg) = f(h'g) \implies h = h'$

onto: $\forall h \in H \, \exists\, hg \in Hg \,\,s.t.\, f(hg)=h $

This doesn't seem correct.

Comment: This is exactly it!

Comment: gotta love math, some questions are so simple that they make you question everything. thank you!

Comment: Knowing when not to second guess yourself is an important thing to learn in math.

Comment: Notice that your function is actually the same as right-multiplying by $g^{-1}$, and that right-multiplication by $g$ is a two-sided inverse to that function (under composition).

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is perfectly OK and you should remember that cosets of a subgroup have the same cardinality as the subgroup in question.